# Triggering Jenkins build on both new tags & commits

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using the Git Plugin : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Currently, via webhooks we start a Jenkins build whenever a change is pushed to GitHub. Now we want to trigger the same build when a new tag is added. So we have two triggering conditions :

1. A code change is pushed to GitHub
2. A tag is created

If we try the fix mention in this thread then the builds start only for tags. [jenkins trigger build if new tag is released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742847/jenkins-trigger-build-if-new-tag-is-released)

How can we do it for both scenarios ?

Question # 02 : How can we get the tag name inside a Jenkins build, is there any environment variable for it.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @SaulCruz : I am not working on this project anymore and have hazy memory, but I think at the time we didn't find a good solution for it. One solution that I thought of was to start two seperate jobs : one triggers for git commits and the other for tags, and they trigger a common second job. Pipeline plugin can be helpful with that. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I'm doing now, will see if I can find something bettter :) cheers

Answer (score 4):

**4 Step Process:**

1. Commit Code : `git commit -m "Some meaningful message"`
2. Create a tag

   - To release to stage : `git tag -a release_stage_<meaningful tag>`
   - To release to prod : `git tag -a release_production_<meaningful tag>`
3. Push the tag : `git push origin release_stage_<same_meaningful_tag>`
4. Push Commit
   `git push origin <branch_name>`

**Jenkins File:**

```
        properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'GitHubPushTrigger']])])
        checkout scm
        git_branch = env.BRANCH_NAME
        git_branch_to_release = env.BRANCH_NAME
        git_tag = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'git tag -l --points-at HEAD'
```

`//And now you can use to do anything with tags`

```
if(currentBuild.result=='SUCCESSFUL' || currentBuild.result=='SUCCESS' || currentBuild.result == null) {
    if (git_tag.contains('release_stage') || git_tag.contains('release_production')) {
        // Do anything which you want to do with tags
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Jenkins GitHub Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin)

It works perfectly well for us for both tag created and changes pushed.

For tags you can use **${GIT_BRANCH}** environment variable, it should contain the tag in **origin/tags/%tag%** format

Comment: Riverfall :  We are using the GitHub PLugin you mentioned. Can you please tell me, how you set it up to work for both tags and branches?

Thanks, let me try the ${GIT_BRANCh} for tags!

Comment: 1.Branch specifier should be empty
2. Option "Build when the change is pushed to GitHub" should be enabled
3. In GitHub webhook options you should choose "send me everything"

Comment: thanks for this answer, can you elaborate more this? when we specify the RefSpec to use +refs/tags*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/* it won't take the regular push to branch changes, only the tag creation