# How to access git tag name from within Jenkins declarative pipeline script and build when new tags are pushed to git

Tags: git, jenkins, github

At the moment I am detecting if specific commits are tagged, and have a stage which only gets executed when a tag matches a specific string.

```
stage('Do this only on tagged commits') {
    when { tag "test*" }
    steps {
        echo 'Processing files for tag: $TAG_NAME'
    }
}
```

How do I access the current tag string so I can output this message correctly? Also, how do I tell jenkins to trigger build when new tags are pushed to git? At the moment developers commit into branches and then tag them as required. I want to detect that, run the build so the steps specific to tagged commits get executed. Please not this is a declarative pipeline script, which is stored in the repo along with the source.

Comment: I am aware of this question but it does not quite help me. I would like to use the best practice and not run scripts.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809254/triggering-jenkins-build-on-both-new-tags-commits