# How to configure jenkins to release software depending on a git tag?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am trying configure a Jenkins **Pipeline** to carry out the following task:

1. Git lab starts a Jenkins job using Web Hook.
2. Pull data from git repo. (Done)
3. Start a docker container to test an Angular app. (Done)
4. Download Google chrome and install in the docker container. (Done)
5. Run the Angular tests using Karma. (Done)
6. Check if the commit has been tagged as `Release`.
7. If it is not the case then stop.
8. If it is the case then Deploy the application to test env.

**What's blocking the progress:**

- I have no clue how to check if the Git commit is tagged as `Release`
  or not.
- How to stop the build if the tag is not present in the tag?

I have also noticed by outputting `GIT_COMMIT` env variable that it is always null

```
echo "Commit: ${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
```

pipeline {

```
agent none

stages {

    // Starge 1: Get the data from git
    stage('Preparation') {

        agent any
        steps {

            git branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'MY_CREDENTIALS', url: 'http://gitlab/root/test2.git'
        }
    }


    // Stage 2: Build the image and test the repo
    stage("Start docker and run the tests") {

        agent { 

            //dockerfile true

            docker {
                //image 'node:latest'
                image 'teracy/angular-cli'
                args '-u root --network=gitlab_inet'       
            }

        }

        steps {
            echo "Tag: ${env.BUILD_TAG}"
            sh 'wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb &>/dev/null'

            sh 'dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install'
            sh 'rm -f google-chrome-stable_current_amd64*'

            sh 'export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome'

            sh 'ng -v'
            sh 'npm install && npm run test'
        }

    }


}
```

}

**Notes about the configuration:**

I am using gitlab and using the gitlab plugin on Jenkins.

**Notes about pipeline**

I know that using free style build I can specify the tag inside the `Refspec` field. however I want to build a pipeline and spawn a docker container for each build.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'url-to-my-gitrepo.git'
            }
        }
        stage ('Optional Deploy') {
            when {
                expression { 
                    TAG = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'git tag --contains ' + "\$(git log --pretty=format:%h -n 1)" + ''
                    return TAG == 'Release' 
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Commit contains a tag RELEASE'
                echo 'Deploying'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

This will first checkout your master branch. Then it will go through an expression. I create a variable `TAG`. This tag contains the TAG which is on your commit. So to understand, first I'll get the last commit of my repo:

```
git log --pretty=format:%h -n 1
```

Then I will check if there is a tag on that specific commit and I trim the output:

```
git tag --contains COMMITHASH.trim()
```

At last I'm going to compare if the `TAG == 'Release'`.
If it is, it will go in the next `steps` part and `echo` the 2 things and you can start the deploy. If it does not match the pipelines finished and cleans everything in the post section.

Answer (score 0):

Since [2018-04](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/09/whats-in-declarative/), there is a special "stage-when-tag" directive for this:

> tag
>
> Execute the stage if the `TAG_NAME` variable matches the given pattern. For example: `when { tag "release-*" }` If an empty pattern is provided the stage will execute if the `TAG_NAME` variable exists (same as `buildingTag()`).

- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when via https://stackoverflow.com/a/59401175