# Jenkins - Trigger build if new tag is released from Pipeline job

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to trigger a build whenever a new tag is released. I see this issue has been addressed before here: [jenkins trigger build if new tag is released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742847/jenkins-trigger-build-if-new-tag-is-released), however I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this with a Pipeline Job.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a git event for tag push (I am using this in gitlab for pipeline):
[image: Gitlab trigger]