# How to trigger Jenkins job automatically when new tag is added to a remote branch

Tags: jenkins, github

These days I am trying to configure a Jenkins job which will be triggered by tag added to remote branch. Following are the steps what I did:

1. Added hook on github side and set the event to "*Branch or tag creation*" (I can see the hook is correctly triggered on github (enterprise version)).
2. Create freestyle jenkins job (pipeline should be similar), in the git section configure git as below.
   [image: git conf]
3. Check "*triggers "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling*" in Build triggers section

Then I try to change something and add tag to branch, and push to remote.
But still cannot trigger the job run on Jenkins automatically. I have searched a lot but still cannot make this work.
But when I change the event to "*Pushes*" on github side (others keep the same), then the job can be triggered.

Anyone have the idea? Thanks.

And how about Jenkin2 pipeline? No git section in job configuration.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742847/jenkins-trigger-build-if-new-tag-is-released/38998214

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I also found this link and tried every configuration. But none does work. Maybe the Jenkins version are different (jenkins version is old in the link, and I am using version 2.164).

Comment: BTW, I also tried pipeline job. And pipeline job even has no Git inputs as shown in the freestyle screenshot, it only has *Build Triggers* section.