# How to get jenkins to build the latest tag?

Tags: jenkins, github, tags

I've set up a jenkins pipeline job (a single job) that is configured to build tags from a GitHub repo. For this i've set the refspec to the value `+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*` like described here [jenkins trigger build if new tag is released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742847/jenkins-trigger-build-if-new-tag-is-released)

In general, this works. But my repository already contains *many* tags. Every time this job is triggered, it builds one of the tags. To me it looks like it traverses all the tags and if i would hit the build button long enough, it would arrive at the latest tag at some time.

How can i get jenkins to catch up and build the latest tag now and every time it gets triggered from GitHub?

Background: i already had set up a GitHub Org job where it is building *all* tags, but creating a separate job for each tag (multibranch style). This doesn't scale for us, so i don't want this option.