# Jenkins is not automatically building new tags

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using multibranch pipelines. I know Jenkins will not build a tag if the tagged commit has already been built: [jenkins trigger build if new tag is released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742847/jenkins-trigger-build-if-new-tag-is-released)

But Jenkins is not even building tags for new commits for me.

I tried doing this:

```
# create a NEW commit
git commit -am 'new commit' 
# tag after creating this commit
git tag testtag01
# push the tag
git push origin testtag01
```

The tag is discovered but it doesn't do anything. I should be triggering a new build which happens if a new branch is created or if a commit to a remote branch is pushed.

Comment: any update on this? I am facing the same problem