# Trigger Jenkins pipeline when there is a release in github

Tags: jenkins, github-webhook

I am new to Jenkins and I have found some posts regarding this problem in StackOverflow but I haven't been successful so far.

I am using Github Webhook to trigger the Jenkins build and I set "Send me everything" in Webhook config.

However, the pipeline is only triggered when a new commit is pushed to the main but it's not when there is a new release. This is my jenkins pipeline config:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngvdV.png)

Appreciate your help

Comment: If you want to trigger a build anytime a new tag is released, look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29742847/3730626) and its answers.

Comment: @MB it works on freestyle but I don't know why it doesn't on pipeline. The error is "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Ref.getObjectId()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.findRef(String)" is null". 

Do you have any ideas why?